# CustomValidator not fired in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, validation

I have a gridview and i'm trying to create an insert footer. The data inserted must be unique so i have created a custom validator. The problem is that i can;t fire the validator when I am pressing the linkbutton.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonInsert" runat="server" OnClick="updateData">Adauga</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name">

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# "~/login.aspx?UserID=" + Eval("name") %>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" controlToValidate="TextBoxName" Text ="*" ValidationGroup = "INSERT"
                        ErrorMessage="Introduceti numele categoriei" forecolor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorText" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Exista deja categoria" controlToValidate="TextBoxName" ValidationGroup = "INSERT"
                    forecolor="red" OnServerValidate="CheckCategoryAvailability"></asp:CustomValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the backgroud code:

```
    protected void CheckCategoryAvailability(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string textBoxName = ((CustomValidator)source).ControlToValidate;

        var textBox = ((CustomValidator)source).Parent.FindControl(textBoxName) as TextBox;

        string txt = textBox.Text;
        Response.Write(textBox.Text);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Chapter where name = '" + txt +"';", con);
        Response.Write(com.ExecuteScalar());
        int temp = Int32.Parse(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }

    }

    protected void updateData(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        Response.Write(Page.IsValid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place the `ValidationGroup` attribute also in the `LinkButton` tag:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonInsert" runat="server" OnClick="updateData" ValidationGroup="INSERT">Adauga</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Easier Option

Copy custom Validator with different ID but calling the same function passes the textfield value as args parameter

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBusinessName" ErrorMessage="Invalid Text Entered" CssClass="alert-danger" OnServerValidate="customvalidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddress1" ErrorMessage="Invalid Text Entered" CssClass="label-danger" OnServerValidate="customvalidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>

```
Protected Sub customvalidator1_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)        
     If args.Value.contains("X") Then
        args.IsValid = False
     End If
End Sub
```